# How to concat IP set descriptors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When creating `aws_waf_ipset`s in Terraform for the AWS provider, I have multiple lists of IP addresses that I'd like to concat together when creating the `aws_waf_rule`. When I try using `concat` within the `data_id` of the `aws_waf_rule`, I get an error: `* aws_waf_rule.production_wafrule: predicates.0.data_id must be a single value, not a list`.

This makes sense to me, but how would I best create a concat'd list as a resource I can reference in the data ID, if I can't concat it in the `aws_waf_rule` directly?

Here's the example code I had that generated this error:

```
resource "aws_waf_rule" "production_wafrule" {
  name        = "production_WAF_rule"
  metric_name = "ProductionWAFRule"

  predicates {
    data_id =  "${concat(list(aws_waf_ipset.vpn_ipset.id),list(aws_waf_ipset.production_ipset.id))}"
    negated = false
    type    = "IPMatch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`flatten()` (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html) might be what you're looking for.

Not tested but something like this should do it (note that the function takes a single list as its input; you put all of your lists inside of that)-

```
"${flatten([list(aws_waf_ipset.vpn_ipset.id),list(aws_waf_ipset.production_ipset.id)])}"
```

I believe `setunion()` (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setunion.html) will also work on lists (and will dedupe any repeated items).